# Headphones randomly dissapear from sound devices when plugged in

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I factory reset Ubuntu because of this problem and it still lasts even on the newest version. That means there is no user added program that could cause this. I have dual boot and on Windows everything works just fine.

I tried re-downloading pulseaudio and turning auto-mute in alsamixer off.

The only thing that temporarily works is to plug out and plug in the headphones. But after some time I have to do it again.

AUDIO INFO:

Headphones: hyperx cloud alpha s, USB connection

Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)

USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)

Comment: Headphones plugged in to a USB port don't typically use your system's audio adapter because they usually contain their own DAC. Many USB devices will require software or drivers from the manufacturer to work correctly. Have you looked to see if hyperx writes software or drivers for these headphones and if they do, do they write them for Linux/Debian/Ubuntu?

Comment: When I looked for the drivers I found there is some bug with these headphones in the linux, but no fix to it and couldn't find the drivers either.